# How do I add more arguments to a subclass constructor when its super class has fewer arguments?

Tags: java

I tried searching around for an answer to this question but I am either
1. not asking it correctly
2. not thinking straight

Basically, I have an assignment that is a mock grocery store. I have an Item class that I need to use for subclasses that will inherit the traits from the Item class. (inheritance)

Below is what I have so far for this class and its working to my expectations

```
    public class Baguette extends Item {

 int price;
 String name;

public Baguette(String name, int price){
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

}

 @Override
 public String getName(){
   return name;

   }
 public int getCost(){
     return price;
     }

}
```

Now here is the subclass of this Baguette class

```
    public class FlavoredBaguette extends Baguette {
String name;
int price;
String flavor;
int costFlav;

public FlavoredBaguette(String name, int price, String flavor, int costFlav) 
{
    this.name = name; 
    this.price = price; 
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.costFlav = costFlav;
}
}
```

Upon doing this I get this error in the line
constructor Baguette in class baguette cannot be applied to given types
required: string, int
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I know it has something to do with the number of arguments being different but I'm clueless here. Thanks for the help!

Comment: You need to call the `Baguette`'s constructor first, `super(name, price);`, this means that `FlavoredBaguette` doesn't need `name` or `price` as it will inherit these from `Baguette`

Comment: Your `Baguette` class extends `Item` and overrides `getName` ... if this is not an abstract method, it would worry me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call the `Baguette`'s constructor first, `super(name, price);`, this means that `FlavoredBaguette` doesn't need `name` or `price` as it will inherit these from `Baguette`

```
public class FlavoredBaguette extends Baguette {
    //String name;
    //int price;
    String flavor;
    int costFlav;

    public FlavoredBaguette(String name, int price, String flavor, int costFlav) 
    {
        super(name, price);
        //this.name = name; 
        //this.price = price; 
        this.flavor = flavor;
        this.costFlav = costFlav;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, man! I must've missed that part of the lecture. Unfortunately, it doesn't let me click the check just yet.

Comment:  - it's all to easy to miss :P

Answer (score 1):

For extending, you don't need to declare the fields of the super class. also in the constructor, simply call `super()` with the parameters name and price.

```
public class FlavoredBaguette extends Baguette {
    String flavor;
    int costFlav;

public FlavoredBaguette(String name, int price, String flavor, int costFlav){
    super(name, price);
    this.flavor = flavor;
    this.costFlav = costFlav;
}
```

edit: looks like MadProgrammer beat me to it :c